# Add class to an element using event.currentTarget.className

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a button with a yellow background, upon clicking the button I would like it to turn black(https://jsfiddle.net/dcq5v6hy/1/). I am trying to do this with a js function and a `button.active` css class (I have never seen `.active`, but I am trying to follow a W3Schools tutorial).

```js
function changeColor(evt) {
  evt.currentTarget.className += "active";
}
```

```css
.tab button {
  background-color: yellow;
}


/* Create an active/current tablink class */

.tab button.active {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="tab">
  <button onclick="changeColor(event)">Click Me</button>
</div>
```

As you can see, nothing happens when the button is clicked. How can I fix this?

Comment: I've created a snippet from your code and it works somewhat. The problem on JSFiddler is that your `changeColor` can't be accessed from the inline script. It has to to with how JSFiddler is setup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try preppending a space in the appended string: evt.currentTarget.className += " active";

Answer (score 4):

Don't use onevent attributes:

```
 <button onclick="lame()">...
```

Use onevent properties or `.addEventListener()`

```
 document.querySelector('button').onclick = notLame;

 document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', notLame)
```

`event.currentTarget` points to the tag that's registered to the event.
`event.target` points to the tag that was clicked, changed, hovered over, etc...
In OP it is one and the same.

It's not clear as to what the problem is except that it's not very useful being stuck in one state. Perhaps you wanted the button to alternate between the two colors?

```
 evt.target.classList.toggle("active");
```

```js
function changeColor(evt) {
  evt.target.classList.toggle("active");
}

document.querySelector('button').onclick = changeColor;
```

```css
.tab button {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.tab button.active {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="tab">
  <button>Click Me</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I wound up only having to prepend a space to the string "active" to get my specific example to work. However, I learned a lot more than I expected from this answer, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I noticed two different issues here:

1) classNames should be joined with spaces, so add a space before active

```
evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
```

2) The function changeColor cannot be found from the DOM. This mainly because your function is declared under the button's HTML. You could set it global by using `window.changeColor =` or changing the order, but I would recommend using `addEventListener` to add the function as a listener. When using this method, you can remove the onclick="" attribute from the DOM.

```
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', changeColor);
```

Comment: I updated your fiddle with those two changes and it seems to work: https://jsfiddle.net/6yhrx8ap/

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with your code. The issue you have is that the function wasn't being loaded in your jsfiddle. When you clicked the button it was failing to call your function.

If you click on the Javascript panel header and change it to the *Load Type* to *No wrap - bottom of head* you will find it works as you intended.